# Character limit for asp label upto 1000 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to restrict my label upto 1000 characters only.
how to achieve this?
please help...

Comment: when or how do you assign it?
 Check before assigning if (text.length > 1000) then do soemething

Comment: How do you place text in label? we cannot place directly. Either we have to assign a string to the label text or some other similar way.
 Like assigning a textbox entered text. ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tyr this code :

```
 string str = "Characters...";
 if(str.length > 1000)
 {
    str = str.SubString(0, 1000);
 }
 lbl.Text = str;
```

Comment: You need to check the length first else you may get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` - Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: Question requirement is not like that

Comment: Dont care about the question. The downvote was for your bad code (I have removed now)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of restricting the length of a label, but as a label has no user input, you can restrict the string property being assigned to it.

```
string s = "long string...";
if (s.length > 1000){
   s = s.SubString(0, 1000);
}
lblMyLabel.Text = s;
```

Comment: that if() is not necessary. you could do: lblMyLabel.Text = "string".Substring(0,1000);

Comment: @yohannesdedope To my knowledge, `SubString` throws an error if the 2nd parameter is longer than the string length?

Comment: @yohannesdedope: That `if()` is necessary if you want to write good code. Each to their own though

Answer (score 2):

As has already been mentioned by @Curt, there is no direct user interaction on a label (as there is on a textbox for instance), so you should restrict string lengths on the server.

As an extra bit to the answers already given, this is the code I use...

```
public string FormatText(string text, int len, string suffix)
{
    if (len != -1 && text.Length > len)
    {
        int pos = text.LastIndexOfAny(" ,.".ToCharArray(), len);
        if (pos == -1)
            pos = len;
        text = text.Substring(0, pos) + suffix;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Then you can call something like...

```
lblMyLabel.Text = FormatText(myText, 1000, "...")
```

What this does is stop words being chopped in the middle, hopefully preventing unfortunately situations.  For instance, the text might contain `he is an assistant` and at exactly 1000 characters it produces `he is an ass`.  My code will output `he is an...`

Comment: Fair point @weston... the function is part of a library of function in my system, and sometimes the length is set via configuration... so just a way of being able to have the configuration set to -1 to say "I don't want any restriction"

Comment: I understand, comments withdrawn. Nice function. +1

Answer (score 1):

Label is not an input but you can cut down the length to 1000 characters if you know it is exceeding your limit.

```
const int limit = 1000;
label.Text = label.Text.Length>limit ? label.Text.SubString(0,limit) : label.Text;
```

Assuming your label is called *label*

Comment: Over complicated, just do the substring.

Comment: @weston I disagree, while you could simplify the ternary statement further, you still need to check the length to prevent, where the label length is less than 1000 so an ArgumentOutOfRangeException isn't thrown

Comment: You're right, sorry, a few of us said the same, non of us tested it!